# Return Minimum value excluding 0 in form calculation

Tags: javascript, math, minimum, calculation

I'm trying to return the minimum value in a series of numeric input fields. When the fields are blank, they are being read as 0.

Math.min is returning 0 unless all fields are populated with values.

See below code, I'd appreciate any help on this.

```
if ($H8M1$ > 0)
{
return(
Math.min(
$H8M1$, 
$H8M2$,
$H8M3$,
$H8M4$,
$H8M5$,
$H8M6$,
$H8M7$,
$H8M8$,
$H8M9$,
$H8M10$,
$H8M11$,
$H8M12$,
$H8M13$,
$H8M14$,
$H8M15$,
$H8M16$,
$H8M17$,
$H8M18$,
$H8M19$,
$H8M20$));

}
```

Comment: Is number `0` valid for your input fields ?

Comment: `Math.min.apply(Math, [$H8M1$, $H8M2$, $H8M3$, $H8M4$, $H8M5$, $H8M6$, $H8M7$, $H8M8$, $H8M9$, $H8M10$, $H8M11$, $H8M12$, $H8M13$, $H8M14$, $H8M15$, $H8M16$, $H8M17$, $H8M18$, $H8M19$, $H8M20$].map(Number).filter(Boolean))`

Comment: @Thomas I was going to post the exact same solution, but this would also filter the number `0` from the inputs.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia  Ain't that what he asked for? Then a different filter: `.filter(v => !isNaN(v))` or `.filter(v => +v === +v)`

Answer (score 1):

An empty field in javascript is a *falsy* value and in this case the parser force the coercion to a number that is 0 (still a *falsy* value).

you could remove all the empty fields from the calculation or loop over the series and assign the empty elements to the minimum value of the series but in this way your already get the minimum value thus the `Math.min` is not useful anymore.

Answer (score 0):

For each value you are passing to Math.min(), assign 0 to the value if that is blank.

if($H8M1$ == "")
   $H8M1$ = 0;

Comment: He wants to ignore `0` values, not add more of them.